# What's the standard for making plurals of Japanese words in English?

Tags: plurals

There's the movie "Seven Samurai", which would sound strange as "Seven Samurais", but [in the news you often read about](https://www.google.com/news/search?q=tsunamis) "hundreds of tsunamis". Some people say they know 500 kanjis, but I've always thought 500 kanji sounded more correct. Is there any standard way to pluralize Japanese words that are used in English?

(Not sure if this is a good question for here, seeing as it's more about English.)

Comment: Yeah, this is a question about English. You might post it on the [English SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/) but before you do it, check if there are duplicates of your question. :D

Comment: This is a really good question, but I agree with Alenanno that it relates to English language and usage, not Japanese language and usage.  Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: I thought it mightn't fit. OK, close it so.

Comment: I agree that this is off-topic, but I love the question. Could you provide a link here if you decide to post it to a different SE?

Comment: @Derek, may be ["this"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/501/should-transliterated-words-from-non-romance-languages-ever-be-pluralized) is kind of similar question on English.SE site

Comment: @YOU: It is a pity that that question focuses on _whether_ loanwords _should_ be pluralized or not instead of _why_ some loanwords are _actually_ pluralized and the others are not.